# Better name than DELEGATE_TRY_PERFORM_SELECTOR_WITH_SELF

Tags: cocoa, refactoring, naming-conventions

I have a lot of viewcontrollers in my project that just redirects to its delegate.
So I have made a define for it, but I'm not so happy about it's name.

How would you name it or would you do it in another way?

I also have situations where the delegate may return an object or take
multiple arguments.

---

```
// the problem is highly repetitive code    
-(void)switchToNextTab:(id)sender {

    SEL sel = @selector(switchToNextTab:);
    if([m_delegate respondsToSelector:sel]) {
        [m_delegate performSelector:sel withObject:self];
    }
}

-(void)switchToPrevTab:(id)sender {
    SEL sel = @selector(switchToPrevTab:);
    if([m_delegate respondsToSelector:sel]) {
        [m_delegate performSelector:sel withObject:self];
    }
}

-(void)closeTab:(id)sender {
    SEL sel = @selector(closeTab:);
    if([m_delegate respondsToSelector:sel]) {
        [m_delegate performSelector:sel withObject:self];
    }
}
```

---

```
// my solution.. which I need a better name for
#define DELEGATE_TRY_PERFORM_SELECTOR_WITH_SELF(selector_name) \
    do { \
        SEL sel = @selector(selector_name); \
        if([m_delegate respondsToSelector:sel]) { \
            [m_delegate performSelector:sel withObject:self]; \
        } \
    } while(0);


-(void)switchToNextTab:(id)sender {
    DELEGATE_TRY_PERFORM_SELECTOR_WITH_SELF(switchToNextTab:);
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming style. It would be better on the Programmer stack exchange.

Comment: @user1118321 ok feel free to close it. (I cannot delete it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a `Category` on `UIViewController` to give you that method.

Start by creating a `.h` + `.m` file. The convention is normally to use the name of the class you are adding the category to then a `+` then whatever you want to call it. For this example I'll keep it simple (`UIViewController+additional`)

```
// UIViewController+additional.h
@interface UIViewController (additions)
  - (void)MYsafePerformSelectorOnDelegate:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)anObject;
@end

// UIViewController+additions.m
@implementation UIViewController (additions)

  - (void)MYsafePerformSelectorOnDelegate:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)anObject
  {
    if([m_delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
      [m_delegate performSelector:selector withObject:anObject];
    }
  }

@end
```

You then import this file wherever you want to use this method (or consider the `.pch` if it is used throughout your whole project). Now anytime you are in a `UIViewController` sub class (that has the `UIViewController+additional.h` imported) you can call the method

```
[self MYsafePerformSelectorOnDelegate:@selector(closeTab:) withObject:self];
```

NOTE: It is normally a good idea to prefix your method names in categories so that they have less chance of clashing with any internal methods.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This is a much more elegant solution than what I was hoping for.